# Set Image URL based on if condtion on ASPX page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

As of now this code always works on my local and doesnt acts weird. But when we deploy on server even though if **IsEnabled**  value is set to true it will load **isfalse.gif** and therafter few days it will start to load correct image based on **IsEnabled** value.

IsEnabled is an simple property defined in codebehind.

```
protected bool IsEnabled 
{
    get { return Utility.GetValue("TestKey"); }
}
```

Utility class pseudo:

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static bool GetValue(string keyName)
    {
        bool kvalue = false;
        // string value = string.Empty;

        //the below cache is at global level defined below snippet is just pseudo how the data been present 
        Dictionary<string, string> dicCacheDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (dicCacheDictionary.TryGetValue(keyName, out string value))
        {
            if (bool.TryParse(value, out bool result))
                return result;

        }
        else
        {
            //GET FROM DATABASE AND add value to cache
            //for now just for pseudo have hardcoded value
            dicCacheDictionary.Add(keyName, "true");
        }
        //get from DB is not in cache 
        return kvalue;

    }
}
```

ASPX Page :

```
<asp:Image ID="imgWebcast" ImageUrl='<%#(IsEnabled) ? "../../images/istrue.gif" : "../../images/isfalse.gif" %>'  />
```

I looked at below areas and all looks good :

1. Cache precompiled files are deleted prior to deployment
2. Cached is cleared
3. IIS is reset

I can easily set it in code behind and resolve the above , but i need to understand the approach i did above is valid or not. Is something i am doing wrong. Does it achievable from the above approach

Comment: Please show us the definition of `Utility.GetValue()`.

Comment: _"but i need to understand the approach i did above is valid or not. Is something i am doing wrong"_ - Your approach is using WebForms' Data-Binding system, which may not work as you expect if you have non-trivial postbacks. Unless you _absolutely_ know what you're doing in WebForms (and know _exactly_ how Data-Binding works in WebForms, and know **all** the differences between `<%#` and `<%:`, ...and know how to get strongly-typed `Item` working) then I don't recommend it and I suggest you stick with setting it from the code-behind.

Comment: @Dai Utility.GetValue(); this just returns value from dictionary key value based

Comment: What dictionary?

Comment: @Dai Dictionary<string, bool>

Comment: It would be a lot easier for everyone if you just posted your **actual** code to your question post.